# Positioning UIView in UIViewController using NSLayoutConstraints causes aliased UILabel?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios6

I'm trying to manually animate in a UIView, contained in a UIViewController, from the top of the screen. This view will have a height of 150px.

I setup layout constraints for when it's "collapsed" and when it's "expanded" (shown). I animate between the two constraints when I want to hide/show, respectively.

I setup the view contained in this UIViewController in IB with a simple UILabel in the upper-left of the view.

```
CGFloat closeUpViewHeight = 150.f;
self.closeUpViewController = [[[CloseUpViewController_Phone alloc] initWithNibName:@"CloseUpViewController_Phone"
                                                                           bundle:nil]
                              autorelease];

[self addChildViewController:self.closeUpViewController];
[self.view addSubview:self.closeUpViewController.view];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.closeUpViewController.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:nil
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                     multiplier:0.f
                                                       constant:closeUpViewHeight]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.closeUpViewController.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                     multiplier:1.f
                                                       constant:0.f]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.closeUpViewController.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                     multiplier:1.f
                                                       constant:0.f]];

self.expandedCloseUpViewConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.closeUpViewController.view
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                     toItem:self.view
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                 multiplier:0.f
                                                                   constant:0.f];

self.collapsedCloseUpViewConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.closeUpViewController.view
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                      toItem:self.view
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                  multiplier:1.f
                                                                    constant:-1.f];
```

Anyone know why the resulting UILabel has aliasing problems?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed my problem, pretty dumb mistake.

Inside the setup for my view controller, I added a drop shadow to the UIView and accidentally had carried over this:

```
self.view.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
self.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2);
self.view.layer.shadowRadius = 3;
self.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
self.view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;  //<--- Don't rasterize.
```

Removing the `shouldRasterize` line fixes the issue here.